# SWT webkitbrowser and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, webkit, swt, gxt

I am using the WebkitBrowser to run a browser app like on my desktop. I want to know it's possible for the WebkitBrowser widget to listen for javascript calls made when the user interacts with the browser applications' buttons.

I don't know if this will help but I am building the browser app with Ext GWT.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so familiar with WebkitBrowser, but it looks like at the very least you could use a `StatusTextListener` to listen for changes in the status bar text and have Javascript modify that by editing the `window.status` field.

Also, I don't know how attached you are to WebkitBrowser, but the standard SWT Browser widget does support Javascript to Java communication through the [`BrowserFunction`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/BrowserFunction.html) object.

Here's an example of using the `BrowserFunction` class from SWT snippets:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java?view=co

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the SWT browser I will look into it. But I did find that using the JSAlerthandler and browser.execute() allowed me to establish two way communication.